# Shift+K on Vim to open a specific Ruby method

Tags: ruby, vim

I have a file open on Vim with a line of code like:

```
my_hash = Hash.new
```

If I move my cursor over the `Hash.new` and type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> it opens the documentation for the class `Hash` from `ri`.

When I am inside the documentation for `Hash`, I can't move my cursor to other methods listed in there to use another <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to see what that method does. Is there a way to do this? Would be really nice if I could look-up all these docs and methods easily from my Vim instead of opening a browser.

By the way, I have been using the excellent [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)

Comment: I think when you hit `K` you are seeing the output of ri in a pager (most likely more or less). You are no longer in vim. So there is no cursor.

Comment: No. Janus is not excellent. It is a large and unnecessary piece crap. You should drop it as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

When you press **K** over a word, you activate the [man](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_man_pages_in_Vim) page of the word.

If you wanna view the documentation of a specific method inside vim, try the [ri.vim](https://github.com/danchoi/ri.vim) plugin which let you search and navigate Ruby library and gem documentation inside Vim.